# sql query that will get a distinct type, brand, and model, but get a count of how many duplicates were found

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table "Competitor" and here are some of its columns:

```
Type | Brand | Model | Date | Resolution | etc.
```

The table will have duplicate `Model` entries (with obviously same `Brand` as well, but possibly a different `Type` (two possible types: 'ProAV' and 'Disti')). I need to build a query that will output a table like this:

```
Top (ProAV) | Top (Disti) | Last Occurrence | Brand | Model | Resolution | etc.
```

Basically I need a query that will get a **distinct** type, brand, and model, but get a count of how many duplicates were found and put that number in either Top (ProAV) or Top (Disti), whichever `Type` it has. I would need to pull the most recent (given Date) out of the duplicates, so that I can put its Date as the `Last Occurrence` field. I hope this makes sense, let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'ProAV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TopProAV,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Disti' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TopDisti,
       MAX(Date) AS LastOccurence,
       Brand, Model, Resolution
    FROM Competitor
    GROUP BY Brand, Model, Resolution
```

**EDIT**: Based on the comment, you could use a subquery or [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to accomplish what you want. Something like:

```
WITH cteMaxDate AS (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'ProAV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TopProAV,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Disti' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TopDisti,
           MAX(Date) AS LastOccurence,
           Brand, Model, Resolution
        FROM Competitor
        GROUP BY Brand, Model, Resolution
)
SELECT md.TopProAV, md.TopDisti,
       md.LastOccurentce, 
       md.Brand, md.Model, md.Resolution,
       c.AdditionalColumn1, c.AdditionalColumn2
    FROM cteMaxDate md
        INNER JOIN Competitor c
            ON md.Brand = c.Brand
                AND md.Model = c.Model
                AND md.Resolution = c.Resolution
                AND md.LastOccurence = c.Date
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thx for the reply. One question, any additional columns I would want to display I would have to either put in an aggregate function or append in the GROUP BY clause, right? If I put these additional columns in the GROUP BY clause and the data is inconsistent, I will get multiple groups of data, which is not what I want. Is there a way to display the data from the same record that it gets for the "LastOccurrence" field? Or would I have to use some random Aggregate Function and have incosistent data?

Comment: @Nicklamort: See my edited answer for an example of what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm trying your updated query and I'm getting some duplicate Brand/Model records in the result set, any idea why?

Comment: nvm, i figured it out. I had to add the `Type` in the "CTE" subquery and join by that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a limited number of `Type`s? In this case you can solve your problem using pivot
More specifically, for the table

```
Type    Model
----    -----
A       X
B       X
C       Y
A       Z
NULL    NULL
```

you run this query

```
Select Model, [A], [B], [C]
From
(select Model, Type
from dbo.Competitor) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(Count([Type]) for [Type] in ([A], [B], [C])) as PivotTable
```

to get

```
Model    A    B    C
------   -    -   -
X        1    1   0
Y        0    0   1
Z        1    0   0
```